# special table for Vlookup in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am searching for a excel vlookup function, but vlookup table is different.
There are two excel tables.

```
    table 1
one 11 12 13
two 21 22 23 24 
six 61 62

    table 2
11 one
13 one
22 two
61 six
```

So the problem is that I have Table 1 as in input and in Table 2 I have numbers 11,13,22,61 and I have to get from the Table 1 words one, two, six. So this is like Vlookup table but inverse. There are multiple keys in one line and wanted values is the the first column. Do you have some idea how to get these values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a formula like:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$2:$E$4)/($B$2:$E$4=G2),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Like all programs, the programmers think, "This would be cool", and those of us that use it, hate it.  My current job is to think as the user for the program being built.  There have been many instances where I had to reign in the "coolness" factor.

Comment: You would think they would have learned with [Clippy](https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2015/06/clippy-the-microsoft-office-assistant-is-the-patriarchys-fault/396653/) but I guess there is a whole new generation of people to piss off.

Comment: I can still hear the *tink* *tink* that the programmers thought would make it seem like clippy was tapping the glass on the screen.

Comment: Just did Thanks!